# Multi-valued logic in Z3

Tags: logic, z3

I have worked on a 5-valued propositional logic, where there exists five instead of just two truth values, and I would like to use Z3 to reason about this logic.

For the sake of simplicity, assume that the truth values are elements of the set `{0,...,4}` (this is actually a simplification, but should suffice to illustrate my question), which is equipped with the natural order on these elements. Since this logic is no longer binary, operators need to be defined differently, obviously. Examples of the operators are as follows:

- `a and b = min{a, b}`
- `a or b = max{a, b}`
- `not a = 4 - a`

Now, I would like to use Z3 to reason about (quantifier free) formulas in this logic, such as `a or (not b)`. However, I don't know what **(a)** the simplest and **(b)** the most efficient way would be to teach Z3 this.

I guess one straightforward solution would be to use *enumeration sorts* (although I did not yet manage to define them without getting an error) to model the truth values and macros to define the operators. Would that be the route to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following encoding. As Christoph mentioned, QF_BV is very efficient for the given problem.

```
(set-logic QF_BV)
(define-fun myor ((A (_ BitVec 3)) (B (_ BitVec 3))) (_ BitVec 3)
    (ite (bvugt A B) A B))
(define-fun myand ((A (_ BitVec 3)) (B (_ BitVec 3))) (_ BitVec 3)
    (ite (bvult A B) A B))
(define-fun myneg ((A (_ BitVec 3))) (_ BitVec 3)
    (bvsub #b100 A))
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 3))
(assert (bvult a #b101))
(declare-fun b () (_ BitVec 3))
(assert (bvult b #b101))
(declare-fun c () (_ BitVec 3))
(assert (bvult c #b101))

;; test:
(define-fun demorgan () Bool
    (= (myand a b) (myneg (myor (myneg a) (myneg b)))))
(assert (not demorgan))

; (apply (then simplify bit-blast))
(check-sat-using (then simplify solve-eqs (repeat bit-blast) sat) :print_model true)
```

Be noted that for every atomic proposition/variable X you need to add `(assert (bvult X #b101))`.

Answer (score 3):

Enumeration or FiniteDomain sorts might do the job or custom datatypes. Also, an encoding into bit-vectors is possible. Depending on the properties you want to prove later some of these may be more suited than others, but I would directly go for bit-vectors, because they support many different features and functions and they can often be solved efficiently, at least for 'simple' properties. Your mileage may vary of course.